# Vue ionic capacitor not downloading file in android

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, download, capacitor

I am trying to create an app that, with info given by the user, gets a PDF formulary from local assets, writes that info on it and then downloads it.

It works perfectly fine on browser and I get the file sucessfully, but when I create the app build and I try it in the movile device, just nothing happens. I get messages of "File downloaded!" or any log I put, but the file just never start downloading. I already have storage permissions. Just ends the function normally but ignoring the download.

I use the unpkg library to download, but also tried with SaveAs and creating an <a.href> then click it but I got excactly the same result.

This is the full function:

```
    async generateDecklist()
    {
        const formUrl=('../../../assets/decklist.pdf');

        const formPdfBytes = await fetch(formUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());

        const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes);
        const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

        const formFields = form.getFields()

        //START FILLING FORM

        //Deck Name & Nation
        form.getTextField('Deck NameRow1').setText(this.deck.name);
        form.getTextField('ClanRow1').setText(this.deck.nation);

        for (let i = 0; i<this.deck.decklist.length; i++)
        {
            const cs = this.deck.decklist[i];
            const card = Global.cards.find(e => e.id == cs.cardId);

            //Card Name
            const mainDeckCard = "Main deck 50 cardsRow" + (i+1);
            form.getTextField(mainDeckCard).setText(card.name);
            
            //Card Grade
            formFields[16+i].setText(card.grade.toString());

            //Card Amount
            const mainDeckAmount = "Main deck Qty" + (i+1);
            form.getTextField(mainDeckAmount).setText(cs.amount.toString());          
            
            //Card set (Only if there is only one set)
            if(card.sets.length ==1)
            {
                const mainDeckSet = 'No.'+ ((i+13)>=15? (i+14) : (i+13));
                form.getTextField(mainDeckSet).setText(card.sets[0]);
            }

            //Card trigger or sentinel
            let triggerOrSentinel ='';
            if(card.type == 'Trigger Unit')
            {
                triggerOrSentinel += card.trigger; 
            }
            if(card.keywords.includes('Sentinel'))
            {
                triggerOrSentinel += triggerOrSentinel==''? 'Sentinel' : '/Sentinel';
            }
            const mainDecktrigger = "Main deck Row" + (i+1);
            form.getTextField(mainDecktrigger).setText(triggerOrSentinel);

        }

        //END FILLING FORM


        //PROBLEM STARTS HERE
        const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();

        download(pdfBytes, `${this.deck.name}_decklist.pdf`, "application/pdf");

        
        modalController.dismiss();

     }
```

Comment: Where/how are you declaring/importing that `download()` function? Also what is the implementation like? Please share those parts of the code to be able to give you an answer

Comment: I import that function form unpkg when mounting the modal. You can see its implementation in the link where l import it:

`mounted()
    {
        const recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
        recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', "https://unpkg.com/downloadjs@1.4.7")
        document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
    },
`

Comment: Ok and what library are you using for `PDFDocument` and how are you importing it?

Comment: Yes, you've already stated that. I'm asking for the PDFDocument library you are using, which library is it and where are you getting it from?

Comment: I am using PDFDocument from 'pdf-lib'. The PDF file is stored in the assets folder of the project. Im calling it as import
`import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib'`